# DJANGO DEBTORS LIST

Tags: python, django

i have two model with the same names, i want to display its value(display repeated names once) and its summation. what i have been achieved so far is to to do only for Invoice table and working perfect, but when i want to add receiptmodel doesn1t not arrange as invoice arranged

```
model.py

      
from django.db import models

class invoice(models.Model):  
   customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
   total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
   class Meta:
       db_table="invoice"


class ReceiptModel(models.Model):
   customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
   to_amount = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
   class Meta:
       db_table="receiptmodel"
```

```
view.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import  HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
#from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *
from .forms import *#UserRegisterForm, InvoiceForm, LineItemFormset, NewCustomerForm, CustomerReceiptForm
from django.urls import *
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter
from django.db.models import Sum, Q

def ReceivableReport(request): #still not working   
    receivable_inv = Invoice.objects.values("customer").annotate(totinv= Sum('total_amount'))
    receivable_rec = ReceiptModel.objects.values("customer").annotate(totrec= Sum('to_amount'))
    #zipped_data = zip(receivable_inv, receivable_rec)
    #zipped_data = list(chain(receivable_inv,receivable_rec))
    context = {
        'receivable_inv':receivable_inv,
        'receivable_rec':receivable_rec,
    #    'zipped_data ':zipped_data,
    }
    return render(request, "reports/debtorlist.html", context)
```

```
debtorlist.html


<table style="width: 50%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Inv Amount</th>
                        <th>Rec Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for receivable_inv in receivable_inv%} 
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ receivable_inv.customer }}</td>
                        <td>{{ receivable_inv.totinv}}</td>
                        <td>{{ receivable_rec.totrec}}</td>
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
                {% endfor %}

            </table>
```

```
output i want

-----------------------------------------------------
|names  | invoice amount | receipt amount  | balance |
------------------------------------------------------
|per1   |  600           |  400           |  200     |
|per2   |  700           |  300           |  400     |
|per3   |  560           |  160           |  400     |
|per4   |  340           |  240           |  100     |
|per5   |  238           |  38            |  200     |
------------------------------------------------------

output i get

-----------------------------------------------------
|names  | invoice amount | receipt amount  | balance |
------------------------------------------------------
|per1   |  600           |                |        |
|per2   |  700           |                |        |
|per3   |  560           |                |        |
|per4   |  340           |                |        |
|per5   |  238           |                |
------------------------------------------------------
```

it means invoice amount working correctly but i failed to add receiptmodel with the same names.When i try to use `list(chain(table1,table2)` no output in template

Comment: in your template you're only looping through the receivable_inv context object yet you are passing both receivable_inv and receivable_rec so  the output is correct.  It looks like you were trying to chain the querysets together, what was teh output when iterating over the chained results?

Comment: Yes @caleo even in my view I have some comments which means I was trying different way. I tried separate also chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

collector = defaultdict(dict)

def ReceivableReport(request): 
    receivable_inv = 
     Invoice.objects.values('customer').annotate(totinv= 
     Sum('total_amount')).values('customer', 'totinv')
    receivable_rec = 
      ReceiptModel.objects.values('customer').annotate(totrec= 
      Sum('to_amount')).values('customer', 'totrec')
    for collectible in chain(receivable_inv, receivable_rec):
       collector[collectible['customer']].update(collectible.items())
    combined_data = list(collector.values())
    #zipped_data = zip(receivable_inv, receivable_rec)
    #zipped_data = list(chain(receivable_inv,receivable_rec))
    context = {
        
        'receivable_inv':receivable_inv,
        'receivable_rec':receivable_rec,
        'combined_data': combined_data
    #    'zipped_data ':zipped_data,
    }
    return render(request, "reports/debtorlist.html", context)
```

```
<table style="width: 50%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Inv Amount</th>
                        <th>Rec Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% for data in combined_data  %} 
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <td>{{ data.toinv | add:data.totrec }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.totinv}}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.totrec}}</td>
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
                {% endfor %}

            </table>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it's shows all customer list instead of values, and customers list are randomly arranged

Comment: I edited my post and I tried a version of this in shell_plus. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Shows values of receivable_inv for customers and total amount of every customer perfect, in my question as shown in table two I failed to get total of every customers in receipt amount according to customer value list. I want to have one list of customer by merge two tables and avoid duplicate of same customer to appear twice and in total invoice and total receipt to be filled by total. I tried to use for loop twice in template but receipt total can't work as total invoice work. My desire output is table one as how to can work in template

Comment: If you want to add those two variables at the end use:
`<td>{{ receivable_inv.toinv | addition:receivable_rec.totrec }}</td>`
I have also fixed my post accordingly.

Comment: Error, invalid filter 'receivable_rec', or it's there any means to introduce two for loop in template?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think it is a good idea to combine `receivable_inv` and `receivable_rec` into a `union` called combined data and iterate over this data instead which will have all the relevant keys you want. You can find the edited code above.

Comment: Thank you for you support i can say i have 50% achievement. one thing arise instead of `{{ data.totinv}}` to display in its row and `{{ data.totrec}}` to its row also it shows all data vertically in one line. so how can i use `{{ data.totrec}}` to its `<td></td>`  instead of being under `{{ data.totinv}}`. And may be to use one name for both query like output i want table in my question                                                      note: `<td>{{ data.toinv | addition:data.totrec }}</td>` addition produce this error `Invalid filter: 'addition'`

Comment: Hi I have substantially edited the code to fix the two issues you mentioned. Let me know.

Comment: @Yusf Ertas thank you so much for your help, you saved me a lot, the way you did i don`t see myself to solve this problem but now you solved it completely. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you accept my answer and upvote it if you liked my solution? Glad I could help.

Comment: Done, the answer is accepted, but currently i don`t reputation to upvote

Comment: It's ok. No problem at all. Thanks.